# WiX Install over an old (not so good install)

Tags: wix, wix3.8

So I have created a nice new installer using WiX for my customer complete with nice shiny new custom bootstrapper and everyone was happy. However I have struck a problem.

There are a number of user configurable config files installed (yes I know bad idea but I had to work with this). The Component attribute is set to 144 for them which is the `Permanent` and `NeverOverwrite`. So all is fine except I upgrade the old installer (same upgradecode). So the process goes.

1. MSI sees they are there leave them alone
2. MSI Installs files.
3. Now it uninstalls using the logic of the old installer the config files have not changed (I’m guess in real life that would be odd but possible). So it uninstalls them because there was no logic to keep  them in the old installer.

Now I could use a new upgrade code and leave the old installer there but their is a danger then someone will manual uninstall it. (They probably would)

I could use a custom action to copy the files then copy them back but that seems messy.

Anyone had the same problem.... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Components marked permanent are never uninstalled by Windows Installer, so something else must be going on. However if your upgrade installs first, and then the old uninstall runs (RemoveExistingProducts is late) and if you do not have the same component guids for the same files you will get what I can only describe as chaos. The safest approach is to have the RemoveExistingProducts early (after InstallInitialize) if you're not keeping the same component guids.

Comment: Yes I already know that it's the RemoveExistingProduct causing the problem as it was old installer that had no logic to keep the files. I thought about maybe running a patch on the first installer to fix the problem before running mine. I have a question if I move RemoveExistingProducts won't that have the same issue as I still need to keep the config files that are on the machine.

Comment: Another options is a custom action to copy the files out early on then copy then back after. Or I don't upgrade that version at all and simply remove the product from ARP.

Comment: A REP early is basically an unstall of the old product followed by an install of the new. A REP at the end is a guid-reference counted install of new over the old requiring guids to be consistent for the same resources. Again, if those files are permanent they won't be uninstalled, unless your guids are inconsistent (one permanent for the config file, one not) or there is code to explicitly remove them. If you did not retain the same guids for the same resources in your new WiX upgrade an REP at the end is really bad. That's the elephant in the room with unpredictable consequences for any file